# Possible to have a separate html file on wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

There's a member's area of my site and I have a website I made without Wordpress in a local directory on my computer. Is it possible to just have this folder on the server and have one of my Wordpress pages land on this index.html page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Just place the directory on your server like you normally would, and link to it from within WordPress.  The editor will accept absolute paths for link URLs, so if you upload your non-WordPress site to a folder named `newsite`, which would make the URL: `http://example.com/newsite` you can then simply link to `/newsite` when making the link in the WordPress editor.

Comment: so i should drop the folder into the root of my site and then do i create a page and change the URL there? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can just put the folder in your site's root and the server will display it when you go to that url. The only caveat is that the .htaccess set up for permalinks may take the user somewhere else under certain conditions.

So, put the folder in your site's root, and try typing a url like this one:
(your site's url)/(the folder)

Assuming that works, you can copy/paste that url into a menu or put a link on a page or post.